# react-native-elements: The last few items in the Transaction List cannot be viewed at bottom

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/) to speed up the development of my `react-native` app.

I am using `react-native` [ScrollView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/scrollview.html#scrollview) in my [List](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/lists/#list-props) element to enable scroll functionality.

Unfortunately, it seems that the List element is overflowing at the bottom, hiding the last few list item elements from view

[image]

Any idea why this is the case?

EDIT: Here is the render function of the list component

```
render () {
    const { transactions, handleEditTransaction, handleDeleteTransaction } = this.props

    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <List>
            <ScrollView>
            {
              transactions.map((item, i) => (
                <TransactionListItem
                  key={i}
                  item={item}
                />
              ))
            }
            </ScrollView>
          </List>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: What does your style code look like? Set the Scrollview to have flex: 1.

Comment: Scrollview doesn't show if I set style to `flex: 1`

Comment: I'm going to have to see your code. Could you update your question to include that please?

Comment: @Cobolt I have updated my question to show the snippet of code.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To solve this, go to the root `<View>` and add `style={{flex: 1}}`.
This means to also add this to the parent component if necessary.

```
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
   <ScrollView>
     //Content here
   </ScrollView>
 </View>
```

parent component (if required)...

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <ChildComponent />
</View>
```